# (VB.NET) How to read binary file (not like 00 C8 but rather 51200) - Automotive Chip Tuning Software

Tags: binary, binaryreader

I own a Chip Tuning shop in Serbia. I'm developing some software that will make our lives easier in our line of business. I couldn't seem to find a way to create a binary reader that will display both the offset, values and in ascii so I ended up Converting a project I found on the internet that is based on "Be.HexEditor" HexReader tool. The problem is that it only reads in 8bit (I may be wrong I'm not a professional in programing) It reads for instance: 00 C8. But I need it to read: 51200. I don't even know if it's possible to do it with the project I'm currently runing, and with the dll from "Be.Hexeditor" But if anybody could help me I'm willing to pay if somebody won't do it for free.

The source project that I've started:
http://www.mediafire.com/file/lesgx6uybtz6g3j/hexboxreusabletest.rar/file

I may be asking for too much and I know but if somebody is willing to re-edit my project for that to work if it is even possible, it would be much appreciated!

[Here's how it looks now (software screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDqvV.png)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your source codes are a VB.net project.

To convert the value "C800" to "51200", the following codes should be enough

```
Dim hex As String = "C800"
Dim int As Integer = Val("&H" & hex)
```

The int is now 51200

Enjoy...

Comment: Yes it is as I've said. But how can I apply that to my project? To be precise to the "HexBox"

Comment: How can I read a bin file and view the whole bin like XXXXX XXXXX but not like XX XX XX